# Getting a generic type of implementing class

Tags: java, generics, interface

Has this interface:

```
public interface Cloneable<T>
{
    public T clone();
}
```

And it's implementing class:

```
public class Clazz implements Cloneable<Clazz>
{
    public Clazz clone();
}
```

Can i avoid this?:

```
implements Cloneable<Clazz>
```

It will be simply `implements Cloneable`. Sorry for my english, i from Russia...

Comment: You ... don't. At least, not if you want to use Generics.

Answer (score 1):

Well you *could* write `implements Cloneable`, but then you'd be using the *raw* type, which is generally a bad idea.

For the sake of stronger typing, you're better off sticking with what you've got.

Comment: I want that type was that class which implements this interface. Something like: public interface Cloneable<this>

Comment: @user1936245: There's no such construct. You have to do it explicitly to be type-safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave out the `<Clazz>` it is treated as if you used `<Object>`.

If that is acceptable then go for it. Not recommended though unless you really want to lose some of your type safety.

Wasn't there a `Java Puzzlers` that mentioned this ... I can't find it.

Found it [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wbp-3BJWsU8). Go to about 38:00 where they are discussing the `Glommer` type.

Jon is correct - Raw types are not the same as `<Object>` and they **are** scary.

Comment: Raw types aren't the same as just using `<Object>` - the *whole* interface gets erased, even for generic types which have nothing to do with the parameter in question. Raw types are scary.

Answer (score -2):

Solution: `public interface Cloneable<T extends Cloneable<T>>`